Unable to read an excel file (XLSX) in WSO2AM 4.2.0 on an AXIS2 service using Apache POI 3.17.0 library
I am getting error reading an Excel file (XLSX) in WSO2AM 4.2.0 on an AXIS2 service using the Apache POI library 3.17.0.
Initially, i was getting the error below:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.schemas.office.office.CTShapeLayout$Factory cannot be found by poi_3.17.0.wso2v1
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFVMLDrawing.read(XSSFVMLDrawing.java:144) ~[poi-ooxml_3.17.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFVMLDrawing.<init>(XSSFVMLDrawing.java:120) ~[poi-ooxml_3.17.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor765.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:56) ~[poi-ooxml_3.17.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:60) ~[poi-ooxml_3.17.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
    ... 15 more

To resolve the above error, i added the poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar library to the folder <wso2am-4.2.0_home>\repository\components\extensions.
After adding the poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar library, i started getting the error below:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject
    at com.microsoft.schemas.office.office.CTShapeLayout$Factory.parse(Unknown Source) ~[poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar:3.17]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFVMLDrawing.read(XSSFVMLDrawing.java:144) ~[poi-ooxml_3.17.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFVMLDrawing.<init>(XSSFVMLDrawing.java:120) ~[poi-ooxml_3.17.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:56) ~[poi-ooxml_3.17.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:60) ~[poi-ooxml_3.17.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
    ... 15 more

To resolve the second error, i added the xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar library to the folder <wso2am-4.2.0_home>\repository\components\extensions**, but now I am getting the error below:
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:63) ~[poi-ooxml_3.17.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:580) ~[poi-ooxml_3.17.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:592) ~[poi-ooxml_3.17.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:165) ~[poi-ooxml_3.17.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:270) ~[poi-ooxml_3.17.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:184) ~[poi-ooxml_3.17.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:149) ~[poi-ooxml_3.17.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at com.csw.impression.integration.ws.processaficheiros.utils.converter.TransferenciaTelemovelConverter.unmarshal(TransferenciaTelemovelConverter.java:50) ~[?:?]
    at com.csw.impression.integration.ws.processaficheiros.utils.converter.composite.TransferenciaTelemovelLeafConverter.unmarshal(TransferenciaTelemovelLeafConverter.java:19) ~[?:?]
    at com.csw.impression.integration.ws.processaficheiros.utils.converter.composite.CompositeConverter.unmarshal(CompositeConverter.java:74) ~[?:?]
    at com.csw.impression.integration.ws.processaficheiros.utils.converter.composite.CompositeConverter.unmarshal(CompositeConverter.java:111) ~[?:?]
    at com.csw.impression.integration.ws.processaficheiros.utils.converter.AutoDetectConverter.detectAndUnmarshal(AutoDetectConverter.java:99) ~[?:?]
    at com.csw.impression.integration.ws.processaficheiros.utils.handler.HandlerFicheiroEntrada.run(HandlerFicheiroEntrada.java:110) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:56) ~[poi-ooxml_3.17.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:60) ~[poi-ooxml_3.17.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader org.wso2.carbon.server.ChildFirstURLClassLoader @59532566 wants to load class org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions. A different class with the same name was previously loaded by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @27d22b7a. (org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @27d22b7a, parent loader 'app')
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:427) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:421) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:420) ~[?:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.ChildFirstURLClassLoader.loadClass(ChildFirstURLClassLoader.java:62) ~[org.wso2.carbon.server-4.8.1.jar:4.8.1]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.class$(XmlBeans.java:43) ~[xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0-r1364789]
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.buildCompilationMethod(XmlBeans.java:224) ~[xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0-r1364789]
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.<clinit>(XmlBeans.java:130) ~[xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0-r1364789]
    at com.microsoft.schemas.office.office.CTShapeLayout.<clinit>(Unknown Source) ~[poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar:3.17]
    at com.microsoft.schemas.office.office.CTShapeLayout$Factory.parse(Unknown Source) ~[poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar:3.17]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFVMLDrawing.read(XSSFVMLDrawing.java:144) ~[poi-ooxml_3.17.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFVMLDrawing.<init>(XSSFVMLDrawing.java:120) ~[poi-ooxml_3.17.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:56) ~[poi-ooxml_3.17.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:60) ~[poi-ooxml_3.17.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
    ... 15 more

Note: I also tried to put the jars in the folder <wso2am-4.2.0_home>\lib\ , in the folder <wso2am-4.2.0_home>\repository\components\lib\ and in the folder <wso2am-4.2.0_home>\repository\components\plugins\ but without success.
How can i solve the error above?
I tried to add the jars to the indicated folders of WSO2AM 4.2.0 but without success, my expectation is to be able to read the Excel (XLSX) file successfully.
